# Iterating through specified range within js es6 map

Tags: javascript, es6-map

I have a sorted JavaScript map structure storing object states based on time.

`Map(key:time(inMilli), value: {object attributes})`

What I am needing to accomplish is to be able to check map against a start and end time to get a collection of all values between without iterating over the entirety of the map.

```
//currently using something like this. But would like to not compare against entire map of times
let map = dataService.getTimeData()//returns map of all objects
let updates = getRange(someTime, someTime);

function getRange(start, stop){
  let foundValues = [];
  //if start is end or after end time
  if(start >== stop)return [start];

  //search map for values
  for([key,value] of map){
    if(key > start && key < stop)foundValues.push(key)
  }  
  return foundValues;
}
```

Comment: I've not used a map, but couldn't you just use `map.keys()` and iterate over that?

Comment: yes but that would still require iterating over the entirety of the map. What I am looking for is a way to essentially grab two indexes and only iterate over the times that I need.

Comment: as I said, I've not used Map, but from what I know of Maps I don't think you'll be able to accomplish this without going over the entirety of the array.

Comment: Yea, that was my initial assumption but was really hoping that someone would have found a way lol. I did find a library and posted in solution that allows for this and is really handy for client-side data storage and retrieval. Have not tested performance yet but it is looking pretty good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using [jstreemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jstreemap) and using a TreeMap and itterating over their upper and lower bounds functions. This was really easy and would recommend.

```
let map = new TreeMap();//just wanted to show that this is a TreeMap now
map = dataService.getData();

function getRange(startTime, endTime){
  let from = map.lowerBound(startTime);
  let to = map.upperBound(endTime);
  let it = from;//initialize to first value in iterator
  let foundValues = [];

  //only iterates from first object requested to last. No longer needs to search any unnecessary values. 
  while(!it.equals(to)){
    foundValues.push(it);
    it.next();
  }
  return foundValues();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRange(start, stop){

    let foundValues = [];

    if (start >== stop) return [start];

    for(let [key, value] of map.entries()){
        if (key > start && key < stop) {
            foundValues.push(key);
        } else {
            return foundValues;
        }
    }  
    return foundValues;
}
```

You just need to return the array once an entry's time in the map is out of the specified range(start and stop), and this will stop the iteration.

```
function getRange(start, stop) {

  const currentArray = Array.from(map);

  let foundValues = [];
  let currentMap = currentArray.shift();

  while (currentMap[0] > start && currentMap[0] < stop && currentArray.length) {
    foundValues.push(currentMap[1]);
    currentMap = currentArray.shift();
  }

  return foundValues;

}
```

Using while loop, this won't iterate all the items in the map.
This will only work when the map is already sorted.

Comment: This is similar to what I had come up with but really did not want the overhead of converting the entire map to an array. Ended up finding a library called jstree that has a javascript TreeMap with upper and lower bounds functions that can be used for segmenting the map like I was needing.